# Swift alternative to performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: swift, performselector, ios8

I want to reload my table data inside a block in this method:

```
import UIKit
import AssetsLibrary

class AlbumsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var albums:ALAssetsGroup[] = []

    func loadAlbums(){
        let library = IAAssetsLibraryDefaultInstance

        library.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupAll),
            usingBlock: {(group, stop) in
                if group {
                    self.albums.append(group)
                }
                else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    })
                }
            }, failureBlock: { (error:NSError!) in println("Problem loading albums: \(error)") })

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAlbums()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }
```

But the else block will not execute. The error I get is:

```
'performSelectorOnMainThread' is unavailable: 'performSelector' methods are unavailable
```

So what is the alternative to `'performSelectorOnMainThread'` in swift?

UPDATE:

I am now getting an abort error.

Comment: GCD has been preferred over `performSelectorOnMainThread` in Objective-C for a while now, check out the docs here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This simple C-function:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        // DO SOMETHING ON THE MAINTHREAD
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

What about launching your function with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        loadAlbums()

})
```

in viewDidLoad()?

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as your right answer, so that other people see the answer right away :)

Comment: I spoke too soon - I am now getting an error that I don't even know how to debug: http://cl.ly/image/1d272E263V2N - please have a look

Comment: What do you see in the console log when the exception happens (The exception just means that abort() was called)

Comment: I tried this in my own project and also looked for the performOnThrad-methods, they are all deprecated..

Comment: Update your question with the code you're currently using then, because the answer provided should certainly work.

Comment: does your loadAlbums() function even is in another thread than the main-thread? That shouldn't create this error, but just wondering..

Comment: Are you having problems on the simulator, or live device?  I'm seeing the problem only the simulator.

Comment: I had a problem with a resizable cell in a tableview, it resizes depending on if it has a thumbnail or not, and it worked perfect on each device except iPhone 6 Plus, but with that it works perfect! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:
{
    //Code to execute on main thread
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use GCD in lieu of performSelector variations.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        () -> Void in
        self.doSomething()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling **performSelectorOnMainThread** on UIViewController instead of UITableView's object

May be your code:

```
self.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector(reloadData), withObject: self.tblMainTable, waitUntilDone: true)
```

Instead of:

```
self.tblMainTable.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector("reloadData"), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

you are getting that message because UIViewController does't have any method named "performSelectorOnMainThread"

Answer (score 1):

//Xcode 8.2 // swift 3.0

I am accessing an API which gives the data regarding weather i.e 'temperature', 'humidity', 'pressure' etc after submitting the name or zipcode of any city.
So, That data need to be shown(*It must be on Main Thread*) on UI (*the tableView*)

```
self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(Home.DataOnUI), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

//

```
func DataOnUI() {

     self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```

P.S. Home is the class of UIViewController

Comment: Please also describe your solution in a few words.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3 / Xcode 8.2**

Here is a Swift 3 way of doing things. Simply insert the time (in seconds) that you would like the code to execute after.

```
let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(20.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
        //Your code to run after 20 seconds
    }
```

Alternatively you could simply place your time delay in one-line notation like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
    // Your code to run after 10 seconds
}
```