# Pull to Refresh in Swift not Reloading UITableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift, pull-to-refresh

I've got `JSON` filling my `UITableView` successfully, but the `JSON` is often updated so I need the ability to refresh. I followed [**THIS TUTORIAL**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24476087/3170671) to implement a pull to refresh control. Visually, it seems like it all works correctly, but when I call `tableView.reloadData()` the table doesn't reload. However, if I leave the `ViewController` and return, the table is updated. Why would `tableView.reloadData()` work in `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` but not in my custom `refresh()` function?

**MainVC.swift file**

```
    class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
        var dataArray: NSArray = NSArray()

        @IBOutlet var Controller: UISegmentedControl!

        var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

        func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
        {
            refreshBegin("Refresh",
                refreshEnd: {(x:Int) -> () in
                    self.tableView .reloadData()
                    println("Table Reloaded")
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            })
        }

        func refreshBegin(newtext:String, refreshEnd:(Int) -> ()) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                println("refreshing")
                sleep(2)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    refreshEnd(0)
                }
            }
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            self.tableView .reloadData()
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logojpg.jpg"))
            startConnectionAt("http://www.domain.com/json.php")


            refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
            refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh")
            refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

            }

//MARK: JSON Loading

    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    func startConnectionAt(urlPath: String){
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
        connection.start()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Connection failed.\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didRecieveResponse response: NSURLResponse)  {
        println("Recieved response")
    }

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        self.data = NSMutableData()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        var dataAsString: NSString = NSString(data: self.data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var err: NSError
        var json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        var results: NSArray = json["needs"] as NSArray
        self.dataArray = results

        tableView.reloadData()
        println("success")
    }

//End loading of JSON

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataArray.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomCell

        var rowData: NSDictionary = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
        var firstName=rowData["needFirstname"] as String
        var descrip=rowData["needDescription"] as String
        var poster=rowData["needPoster"] as String
        var city=rowData["needCity"] as String
        var state=rowData["needState"] as String
        var country=rowData["needCountry"] as String

        cell.needFirstName.text = firstName
        cell.needDescription.text = descrip
        cell.needDescription.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.needPoster.text = poster
        cell.needCity.text = city
        cell.needState.text = state
        cell.needCountry.text = country

        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func Change(sender: AnyObject) {

        if Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            startConnectionAt("http://www.domain.com/localJSON.php")
        }
        else if Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            startConnectionAt("http://www.domain.com/intlJSON.php")
        }

        self.tableView .reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey David - I just tried to replicate a simple example without web service calls and mine worked.  Where is it that you're setting dataArray to a new NSArray?

Comment: I'll add the rest of my MainVC file

Comment: To answer you're question Andrew, the dataArray is pushed into a new NSArray "results" in the connectionDidFinishLoading function

Comment: I see `self.dataArray = results` and `tableView.reloadData()` in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method.  However, I don't see where you actually make another call out to your service to let this callback method actually get executed again during your manual pull to refresh process.  The `refresh` function simply calls `tableView.reloadData()`, but since there's nothing new in the array (because no web service has been called), nothing get's reloaded... unless I'm missing something else in your approach...

Comment: So does that I mean I need to push results yet again into a new NSArray inside of my refresh function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last comment is right-on in my view.

During your pull to `refresh` function, you call `tableView.reloadData()`, however, `reloadData()` does not inherently do any repopulating the elements in the data source (in your case, `dataArray`).  It simply reloads all the data that's currently *in* the table view's data source at the time it is called.

So my recommendation would be to construct your `refresh` function such that the following happens:

1. Initiate a request to your web service.
2. When the response comes back (ie, `connectionDidFinishLoading` is executed), parse the JSON results and assign that result to the dataArray instance.  You seem to be doing this already in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, so it's just a matter of sending the request to your web service, I'd think.
3. Call `tableView.reloadData()` to display any new elements that have been added since the last time the tableView's data was displayed.  Again, you're doing this already in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, so #1 is the primary thing that I think needs to happen.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957339

Not sure but maybe the connection is run on a different thread, if so you need to run the table update on the main UI thread

```
// using Swift's trailing closure syntax:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Reload table in mainThread in swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126261/swift-alternative-to-performselectoronmainthread/31853168#31853168

Comment: It needs a parentesis :) 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }